# Writing a vertical menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've started a vertical menu here: http://jsfiddle.net/1___/bjXp2/1/

I have a few questions:

1) How do i make 'onmouseover' only show the .myList that belongs to the .title I mouse over, instead of all the .myLists?

2) For the .myLists, I'd like to center align them based on their size. Meaning: I mouse over the .title, and a .myList appears. However, for big .myLists or small .myLists, they all display equal numbers of sub items above and below my cursor.

Thanks! I feel like I'm making lots of progress on this menu. --are there any other good examples of jquery vertical menus out there?

**edit** sorry, I may have confused some. I wasn't looking for an accordion menu, instead i was looking for something like Ulan Murzatayev suggested. ..now the question is: how do i handle the mouse out event/position the .myList to the right as so a mouseout doesn't happen prematurely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/bjXp2/44/

Comment: This is great! ..my last question is: what's the best way to position the .myList so that I can get to .myList without firing 'mouseout'?

Comment: You can add a small timeout before hiding the list, after which you will check if the mouse is on the `.mylist` element, if it is then don't do anything, if it not, then hide `.mylist`. I also suggest going over  examples that @woodykiddy posted

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/bjXp2/27/

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of examples available out there. All you need to do is just do a quick google search.

Anyway, here's some of links to those examples that you may find helpful.
[Example 1](http://www.w3csolutions.com/website-resources/category/Vertical-Menu/jQuery-Menu/)
[Example 2](http://www.queness.com/community-news/11376/15-jquery-vertical-menu-examples)

If you are interested in vertical accordion menu style, check below link
[jQuery Simple Vertical Accordion Menu](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-vertical-accordion-menu/)